# Connection timeout in http requester in mule

Tags: connection, timeout, mule, mule-studio

I hitting multiple url in http requestor in mulesoft

```
     For example:-abc.com
                  def.com
                  ghy.com
                  xyz.com
```

But in "def.com" I am getting connection time out error(no response code is coming) and i know because site is down but once i got this error my flow got stopped and not going forward for another website i.e "ghy.com" etc..

Can you please tell me how to make flow in continue processing  even i got connection time out for particular website

I have tried catch exception strategy but i caught this exception but not able the proceed the flow.

Comment: On an unrelated note, can you parallelize the requests? It sounds like you don't need the output of one to proceed with the next.

Comment: hey George,
Can you please elaborate solution not able catch your point. :-)

Comment: If you have a new question, ask it using the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Please don't edit your existing questions completely changing the meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following.

1. Put "def.com" HTTP request component in a private flow.
2. Add a "catch exception strategy" on that private flow
3. Add a flow reference from original flow to private flow.

The catch exception should handle the error on private flow, and when it returns to original flow (calling flow), it should continue processing.

**EDIT**

Here's what I mean. test2Flow is the main flow, then you got `foreach` component somewhere there. It will call a private flow.

The private flow does the HTTP request call where the URL comes from payload. It has catch exception strategy to handle errors from this HTTP request.

Here, `foreach` loop should not stop when error occurred inside the private flow.

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="#[payload.url]" port="#[payload.port]" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
<flow name="test2Flow">
    <!--get list -->
    <foreach doc:name="For Each">
        <flow-ref name="payload" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
    </foreach>
</flow>
<flow name="test2Flow1">
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <!-- store response -->
    <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

Comment: Hey Tyrone,
Thanks for reply,

Comment: I don't think you can suppressed the timeout exception on HTTP requester.. See edit re-private flow - should still work from my understanding.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with that. Seems grizzly implementation already.. Try altering request config (eg. remove persistent connection) or reducing URLs to execute, and see if error remains.